# Vertical align text inside div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know this question has been asked billion times, I searched a lot of solutions but none of them seem to work for me. So, I want to  vertical center simple `<h1>` and two `<h3>` tags. Down below is a code and link to fiddle.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q38o6cxe/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` and `display:table-cell` for your parent tag.

```
  #jumbotron-second {
      background: url(../img/wallpaper.jpg);
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/q38o6cxe/2/)

Comment: Yes that seems to work but it looks like this two properties disable width property because the image now doesn't have width of 100%.

Comment: It is working fine. check this http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/q38o6cxe/3/ I have added some sample background.

Comment: which version? i checked in chrome only.

Comment: I'm testing in latest version of chrome. I have also tried with your photo, same result. Here is a screenshot: http://shrani.si/f/2S/ie/4ppWjZ0g/chrome.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
        #jumbotron-second h1 {
          color: black;
          word-wrap: break-word;
          font-size: 60px;
          text-align:center; // added
        }
        #jumbotron-second h3 {
             color: black;
             text-align:center; // added
        }
```

do you mean something like this?